# Writing a script that executes a different script in many directories

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have a music directory. In this dir, I have multiple folders, all of them with different names which have no pattern. [ex. Daytona OST, sonic cd, etc.].

I would like to run a script in all of them that converts all of the .flac into .mp3, but I can only run that script one by one.

Can I essentially write a script, that cd's into the first directory, executes the script, comes back out, and cd's into the second directory, and does it all over again?

The folders have no pattern, so I don't think there's a way to do it with a wildcard.

For ease's sake, the script I want run in every directory is called `conversiontomp3.sh`.

Comment: The pattern is that they're folders. You can use `for dir in */; do ( cd "$dir" && conversiontomp3.sh ); done`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Guess I need to learn more shell...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `globstar` and grab all your .flac files in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.flac; do
  [[ -f $f ]] || continue # skip if not a regular file
  conversiontomp3.sh "$f"
done
```

Assumption here is that the conversion script saves the mp3 file in the same directory as where the .flac file is.  If that is not true, you may need to grab the directory of the .flac file and pass the output file name to the script.